# How to extract urls from HYPERLINKS in excel file when reading into scala spark dataframe

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an Excel file with **Column A** containing HYPERLINKS like this:

`=HYPERLINK("https://google.com","View Link")`

[image]

I can load the Excel file in scala spark dataframe  using **com.crealytics.spark.excel** library but only with the '**View Link**' text which DOES NOT contain the url

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object Tut {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("started")

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("MySpark")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("A", StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField("B", IntegerType, nullable = false)))


    val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("useHeader", "true").schema(customSchema)
      .option("dataAddress", "A1")
      .load("/MY_PATH/src/main/resources/SampFile.xlsx")

    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
  }

}
```

[image]
[image]

My goal is to load the entire content of the HYPERLINK as a string:
`=HYPERLINK("https://google.com","View Link")` 
and then extract the url
`https://google.com`.

Do you know if there is a way to do this using **com.crealytics.spark.excel** library or any other spark library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, seems interesting, I read the options available for excel in com.crealytics.spark.excel docs, and there was no options available for this, maybe you can raise an issue. Anyway, using BinaryType instead of String type might help you (value is an Array[Byte], seems like it gives you the raw bytes without any pollutions, then convert it to string). create a struct with BinaryType, read the data from the file using this struct, then using a udf, you can both extract and create the new struct in a single function, returning the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @AminMal! I tried your suggestion but it seems to struggle to load the column as Array[Byte]. Here's what I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72035750/how-to-read-excel-file-column-as-binarytype-in-scala-spark-dataframe-and-convert

Answer (score 1):

About the other question link you provided in the comments, they're trying to read the column as `BinaryType`, and cast it out of the box into `StringType`, well, such thing is not possible (even in scala itself), since you need to know how to read the bytes and represent it as a human readable string, right? for instance the encoding, etc.

Now we know that we need to define a custom approach. I used a sample in-code dataframe, and this approach worked:

```scala
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val df = Seq(
     |   ("ddd".getBytes, 1)
     | ).toDF("A", "B")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: binary, B: int]

scala> val btos: Array[Byte] => String = bytes => new String(bytes) // short fot bytes to string
btos: Array[Byte] => String = $Lambda$2322/665683021@738f6e44

scala> spark.udf.register("btos", btos)
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = SparkUserDefinedFunction($Lambda$2322/665683021@738f6e44,StringType,List(Some(class[value[0]: binary])),Some(btos),true,true)

scala> df.withColumn("C", expr("btos(A)")).show
+----------+---+---+
|         A|  B|  C|
+----------+---+---+
|[64 64 64]|  1|ddd|
+----------+---+---+
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Really appreciate the help but still no luck:

val btos: Array[Byte] => String = bytes => new String(bytes)
val myBtos = udf(btos)

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("A", BinaryType, nullable = false),
      StructField("B", IntegerType, nullable = false)))
    val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("header", "true").schema(customSchema)
      .option("dataAddress", "A1")
      .load("./src/main/resources/MyFile.xlsx")

    df.printSchema()
    df.select( myBtos(col("A").as("D"))).show()

gives empty column

Comment: @wavemonger I see, that makes sense. there is probably an issue in spark. I have not tried this yet, but you also might want to create a custom datatype? that describes how to read data into that type. I took a lot on the internet about how to implement a new DataType but couldn't find anything useful. Try looking for something similar on the internet. your first line to go for the implementation is: `object HyperlinkType extends DataType {...}`